# Converting to async calls for Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm going to start out by saying this is the 1st python program I have ever written and have no real background in the language so my code is probably pretty rough. Take it easy on me!

When I wrote this it works fine for a small number of tickers but when I have a file with 6k+ it is very slow. Now I know there are other ways I can improve performance BUT I want to try and tackle the async thing first.

I thought it was as simple as making the read_ticker_file function async and adding await in front of the yfin_options() call but obviously that didn't work.

I'm thinking possibly I need to restructure the way things are called but kind of stuck here. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction! Thanks in advance

```
import logging
import pyodbc
import config
import yahoo_fin as yfin
from yahoo_fin import options
from datetime import datetime, date
from selenium import webdriver


def main():
    read_ticker_file()


def init_selenium():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(config.CHROME_DRIVER)
    return driver


def yfin_options(symbol):
    logging.basicConfig(filename='yfin.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.basicConfig(filename='no_options.log', level=logging.ERROR)

    try:

        # get all options dates (in epoch) from dropdown on yahoo finance options page
        dates = get_exp_dates(symbol)

        # iterate each date to get all calls and insert into sql db
        for date in dates:
            arr = yfin.options.get_calls(symbol, date)

            arr_length = len(arr.values)

            i = 0

            for x in range(0, arr_length):
                strike = str(arr.values[i][2])
                volume = str(arr.values[i][8])
                open_interest = str(arr.values[i][9])
                convert_epoch = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(date))
                try:
                    sql_insert(symbol, strike, volume, open_interest, convert_epoch)
                    i += 1
                except Exception as insert_fail:
                    print("I failed at sqlinsert {0}".format(insert_fail))
            file_name_dir = "C:\\temp\\rh\\options{0}{1}.xlsx".format(symbol, date)
            logging.info(arr.to_excel(file_name_dir))

    except Exception as e:
        bad_tickers_file_dir = config.BAD_TICKERS
        f = open(bad_tickers_file_dir, "a")
        f.write(symbol)
        f.write('\n')


def sql_insert(symbol, strike, volume, open_interest, exp_date):
    conn_string = ('Driver={SQL Server};'
                   'Server={0};'
                   'Database={1};'
                   'Trusted_Connection=yes;').format(config.SERVER, config.DATABASE)
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    insert_string = """INSERT INTO dbo.options (Ticker, Strike, Volume, OpenInterest, expDate)
                    VALUES
                    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""

    cursor.execute(insert_string, symbol, strike, volume, open_interest, str(exp_date))

    conn.commit()


def get_exp_dates(symbol):
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + symbol + "/options?p=" + symbol
    chromedriver = init_selenium()
    chromedriver.get(url)
    # Yahoo Finance options dropdown class name (find better way to do this)
    select_dropdown = chromedriver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='Fl(start) Pend(18px)'] > select")
    options_list = [x for x in select_dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
    dates = []
    for element in options_list:
        dates.append(element.get_attribute("value"))

    return dates


def read_ticker_file():
    file1 = open(config.TICKER_FILE, 'r')
    lines = file1.readlines()

    count = 0
    # loop to read each ticker in file
    for line in lines:
        count += 1
        line = line.strip('\n')
        line = line.strip()
        yfin_options(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Put your question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Check `asyncio` and learn its basic grammar. This post might be a start - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410035/how-to-do-unit-tests-on-python-async-functions/